# SC CreateService FAILED 1057 The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified

Tags: cmd, windows-services

I am trying to install winodws service on remote system which is under same network, using below command from cmd.

```
sc \\11.130.23.105 create "test_service01" binpath= "\11.130.23.105\ServiceLocation\TestWindowService.exe" obj= user password= password123#
```

when try to execute above command I m getting below error.

[SC] CreateService FAILED 1057:  The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified. I m verifies that user and passwords are correct. any one can suggest what might be the problem here. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If the target machine is in a domain, you need to specify the user like this:

```
sc \\11.130.23.105 create "test_service01" binpath= ... obj= .\user password= pwd123
```

Also note that the path to the executable should be provided from the perspective of the remote machine, i.e., it should be a local path rather than a UNC path.

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks! The user must be specified using <domain>\<username>.

Unfortunately this format is not specified at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/251192/how-to-create-a-windows-service-by-using-sc-exe